# What Excel formula can I use to combine duplicate entries with both unique data and overlapping data into a single line item?

Tags: excel

I have a large dataset of shipment tracking numbers and costs associated with transportation, surcharges, and duties & taxes. The majority of the tracking numbers are unique, but a meaningful minority are duplicates. Many of the duplicates introduce new information, i.e. the first entry contains costs associated with transportation and associated surcharges, whereas the second entry contains costs associated with duties & taxes, which are mutually exclusive costs from the transportation and surcharges. There are, however, a smaller minority of duplicate tracking numbers that contain new costs associated with the same surcharges included in the original entry. When a duplicate tracking number introduces new cost categories and amounts, I need to combine the new information on the duplicate tracking number by adding the surcharge category and associated cost to the right of the existing information in a single line item. When a duplicate tracking number has a categorical charge overlap with the original, I need to add the costs associated with the duplicate surcharge across the duplicate tracking numbers into a single cell. In many cases, duplicate tracking introduce both new categories of surcharges and associated costs and overlapping categorical surcharges that need to be summed together across original and duplicate tracking.

I have tried a combination of nested VLOOKUP, INDEX, and ADDRESS functions to no avail.

Example - 3 duplicate entries:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Comment: In the source table you have rows with three text/value pairs each. In the desired result, you have seven text/value pairs. Are the text parts of the desired result static and you only want to calculate the numbers, or could there be cases where the result has more than seven text/value pairs? i.e. can each source line item arbitrarily introduce new descriptions that have not been used before?

Comment: You can ignore the specific number of text/value pairs in the source - in this example, each duplicate tracking contained three text/value pairs. I want the output to look across the source, and for all unique text entries across the text/value pairs in the source, return the unique text/value pairs in a single row. Where there are duplicate text entries, i.e. "Discount" and "Fuel Surcharge", sum the values for the output and pair the summed values with the unique text, which was duplicated in the source, and add the text/(summation)value pairs to the output row. Order does not matter.

Comment: I can't ignore the specific number of text/value pairs, because they are instrumental in building the formula. If there is only ever 7 possible text values, the solution will look different than if there is an infinite number of possible text values.  In any case, if there is such dynamic involved, you won't be able to use a formula.

Comment: The max number of text/value pairs I have come across for a single line item is 10. The total number of unique text entries is 52, though I have not come across > 10 being associated with a single line item. Assume max is 10 text/value pairs.

Comment: How many columns will the source table have? Does the number of columns vary or is it the same?

Comment: I would think VBA would be a preferred solution.  You can then handle any number of text/value pairs; and any number associated with a single line item.

Comment: May I know why you need the result to layout like that? For instance are you going to use it as a source data for other system or database? In my opinion the layout of your desired result is not ideal for analysis or charting. It would be better if it only has three columns: Tracking numner, Charge Type, Charge Amount. If you can accept this type of layout there is a lot of way of achieving it.

Comment: In addition to @TerryW suggestion, consider also a layout with one column for the ID, and separate columns for each of the different types of charges (instead of pairs of columns).  That way you'd be able to easily total both the charges for each ID, and also the charges for each type of charge.

Comment: Agreed @TerryW - the format is not ideal. I am going to sue the output of this exercise as a source for a template that I have configured that includes the surcharges as columns (i.e. Discount, Fuel Surcharge, etc.), Tracking Numbers as rows, and the $$ amounts will populate in the array.